# ClickListner is not working on SearchView

Tags: java, android

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                app:queryBackground="@color/white"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:showAsAction="always"
                 app:queryHint="Search Medicines">
            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

This is my xml of searchView,SetOnclicklistner is not working,when i type any character its working fine but when i click nothing happens.

setOnQueryTextListener is working,
onQueryTextChange is working,
setOnCloseListener is working,but SetOnclicklistner  is not working.

```
 search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.e("my_OnSearchClick","OnSearchClick");
             //not working

        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to use keyboard action button for search click action

Comment: please tell  me the solution @JdPrajapati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
search.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //use this action
        }
    });
```

or

```
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                 //use this action

                search.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: search.clearFocus(); what will happen if i attached this code.

Comment: its remove your search focus

Comment: but, i want when i click on searchview recent items should come so i need setOnclickListner to impliment API and i also want setOnQueryTextListener @Jd Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

I got it done this way. Its working for me.

```
searchView.findViewById<View>(R.id.search_mag_icon).setOnClickListener {
      // your code here  
}
```